# Consuming web services in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I just started playing around with some API's in C#.  In my form I had added a service reference http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx.  Everything works great and I am able to utilize its library.  Now I am trying to use for example http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/apiusage.ashx?key=(key goes in here)&format=xml. [I have a key] Now when I try to use it as service reference I am not able to use.

Do I have to call it in my form instead of referencing it? or do some sort of conversion?  Also does it matter if its xml or json type?

Answer (score 1):

ASMX is old technology and uses SOAP under the hood. SOAP doesn't tend to work with query string parameters, it takes parameters as part of the message.

ASHX is something different (it could be anything, it's one way to write a raw HTML/XML page in .NET), so you can't transfer the method for calling one to the other. It also won't have a service reference, it's likely you request it via a raw HTTP request. You'll need to consuly the service documentation to discover how to use it.

Comment: Note that the issue isn't ASMX vs. ASHX. It's SOAP vs. random.

Answer (score 0):

`worldweatheronline` doesn't return a SOAP-XML that is consumable by a WebService client. Therefore you should download the response and parse it as done with many REST services.

```
string url = "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/apiusage.ashx?key=" + apikey;

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string xml = wc.DownloadString(url);

    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var result = xDoc.Descendants("usage")
                    .Select(u => new
                    {
                        Date = u.Element("date").Value,
                        DailyRequest = u.Element("daily_request").Value,
                        RequestPerHour = u.Element("request_per_hour").Value,
                    })
                    .ToList();
}
```

> ***Also does it matter if its xml or json type?***

No, at the end you have to parse the response by yourself.

```
string url = "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/apiusage.ashx?format=json&key=" + apikey;

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string json = wc.DownloadString(url);
    dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    var jArr  = (JArray)dynObj.data.api_usage[0].usage;
    var result = jArr.Select(u => new
                     {
                         Date = (string)u["date"],
                         DailyRequest = (string)u["daily_request"],
                         RequestPerHour = (string)u["request_per_hour"]
                     })
                    .ToList();
}
```

PS: I used [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) to parse the json string